# Simple.Data.UnresolvableObjectException - No matching procedure found, or insufficient permissions

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, simple.data

I have a SQL 2008 Express DB and am trying to run an insert query.  But every time I run the query I get the UnresolvalbeObjectException.

```
Dim db = Simple.Data.Database.OpenConnection("Server=localhost\SQLExpress,Database=Foo;Trusted_Connection=True;")
Dim item as new with {.Name = "SMITH",
                      .Position = 1}
db.FOO_BARS.Insert(item)
```

The Table schema is

```
CREATE TABLE FOO_BARS(Name varchar(50),
                      Position int)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For starters your connectionstring doesn't look valid to me. You have , (comma) between the server and database setting instead of a ; (semicolon). Try changing it to

```
Database.OpenConnection("Server=localhost\SQLExpress;Database=Foo;Trusted_Connection=True;")
```

For a complete listing of what can be done in a connectionstring for sql server look [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Comment: That was just a mistype on my part.

Answer (score 0):

What Eddy said about the connection string should be the first thing to check.

If the connection string is OK... Well, it's trying to resolve your call as a stored proc, which is what would happen if you called db.Insert(item) or if FOO_BARS had previously been resolved as a schema within the database. Is this code coming from inside a larger application where that might have happened?

It would really help me out if you could post a stack trace on the Google Group.

Comment: Mark I added this to the Google Group as well.  The problem is that Simple.Data does not work with VB.NET.  When I get a chance I will investigate this further.